# JS Obfuscator with modular build support

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Does anyone know if there are any JS Obfuscators available that support modular obfuscation?

I'm basically looking to minimise around 1000 JS files into 5 or 10 obfuscated JS modules.

The main reason for this is so I can continue to patch my app (rather than redeploying the entire app).  I could also then swap some modules for un-obfuscated versions if debugging was required.

It seems many obfuscators such as YUI and Closure Compiler are very basic and don't support much beyond obfuscating a bunch of files.

Thanks

Comment: I was wondering about that. I think you mean obfuscator that does more than just minify- but allow to change variable names (ideally, customize what var names or references you HAVE to keep for some reason, OR instead just propagate all changes upward to the anscestors), and then for it to also update the caller of that JS, etc. Probably some kind of JS package manager combined with an obfuscator - very good question!

Comment: Yep, in the most basic form, a setting which ensures public functions and variables stay the same (but locally scoped variables and functions are minified/obfuscated).  

I've seen the closure compiler uses externs, but there doesn't seem to be any great to support for creating or maintaining externs files.

Comment: Ah, plus I can't use the closure compiler individually on each module as the outputted files won't play nice with each other.

Answer (score 0):

BTW - Found a solution.

The google closure compiler does in fact allow you to compile modules.

There is no documentation that I can find, but if you checkout the code, you'll see how it can be implemented.